# Data Mining from Tripadvisor: source code information with no attribute

Tags: html, r, datetime, web-scraping

I am attempting to mine review data from tripadvisor. I am currently following Hadley Wickham's code ([found here](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/master/demo/tripadvisor.R)). I have got it working for the hotel he is reviewing.

However, when I apply it to my case (eg. [Pichavaram Mangrove Forest](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g790280-d2408767-Reviews-Pichavaram_Mangrove_Forest-Chidambaram_Tamil_Nadu.html)) the dates come out as NA's. 
I have found that the problem is that the dates in his review's source code have the attribute 'title'. None of the sites I am searching have this attribute tag for the date information. Rather when I view my pages' source code, the dates are found in the following line

```
'< span class="ratingDate" >Reviewed 16 May 2015'.
```

Does anyone know how I can modify his code to fetch this date information? 
The date scraping section of Hadley's code is:

```
date <- reviews %>%
  html_node(".rating .ratingDate") %>%
  html_attr("title") %>%
  strptime("%b %d, %Y") %>%    
  as.POSIXct()
```

I am fairly new to R (and coding in general) so I will truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not fair to expect those examples to work 100% of the time given that websites are constantly changing.

Any how... here's a solution that works today...

```
library("rvest")
url <- "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g790280-d2408767-Reviews-Pichavaram_Mangrove_Forest-Chidambaram_Tamil_Nadu.html"
html(url) %>% html_node(".rating .ratingDate") %>% 
  html_text %>%
  strptime("Reviewed %b %d, %Y") %>%    
  as.POSIXct()
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am trying to understand the source coding language so that I can customize the code for myself. So html_text %>% follwed by strptime("quote from source code")%>%

Comment: Is that a fair reflection on you answer? Or is there no simple generalization? Thank you for your code advice. Running your code only gives me one review date (the first review). I am aiming to create a vector with the dates from all the reviews on the page. Did it work in this way on your side? Many thanks.

Comment: change `html_node` to `html_nodes` to get all of the dates.